# How to make a lazyvgrid/ lazyhgrid scroll horizontally maintaining its appearance?

Tags: swift, swiftui, grid, lazyvgrid, lazyhgrid

I’m trying to create a lazyvgrid which has 1 row and scrolls horizontally but i must be missing something since everything I try messes up my layout.

What i want to achieve:
[image]

A grid like this (**with just 1 row**) that is able to scroll **horizontally**.

What I am doing:

- I choose a LazyvGrid because of the way the elements are placed in it .
- I tried with a LazyHGrid as well because since I only need a row it’s not that important how the items are placed in the grid. Anyway the layout looked weird (I had multiple rows that i couldn’t remove).
- Consider that despite my array is static, in real life it will be dynamic

Now I have two solutions which I am not satisfied with:

- The one with the lazyvgrid:

```swift
var days: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[…]

 GeometryReader{ geometry in
 ScrollView(.horizontal){
                LazyVGrid(columns:  [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: geometry.size.width * 0.12))]) {
                    
                   ForEach(days[0..<days.count], id: \.self) {focus in
                      Circle()
                           .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                           .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                   }
           }
       }
}
```

Which results in the following:
￼
[image]

- The lazyHgrid solution:

```swift
 GeometryReader{ geometry in
     ScrollView(.horizontal){
                LazyHGrid(rows:  [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: geometry.size.width * 0.12))]) {
                    
                   ForEach(days[0..<days.count], id: \.self) {focus in
                      Circle()
                           .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                           .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                   }
           }
        }
}
```

And it looks like this
￼[image]
Now here if we change the minimum size to 200 or another big number, i Get 1 row but the collection view remains very tall, instead i only want it to be as tall as the items inside of it are.

for reference, it looks like this:
￼
[image]

Can you explain me how to successfully achieve what i need and why this is happening? I really would like to learn more about grids in swiftui, i was very good with collection views in UIKit and it’s frustrating not having the same with grids…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you set a defined `.frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)` you won't need `GeometryReader`.

You can do either this:

```
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            LazyHGrid(rows: [ GridItem(.flexible()) ]) {
                ForEach(days, id: \.self) {focus in
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
```

or skip Grid entirely and use `LazyHStack`, which would be the more natural pick if you only have one row.:

```
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(days, id: \.self) {focus in
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
```